# Как установить сетевой адаптер, чтобы работал линукс на виртуальной машине?

Tags: администрирование, virtualbox

Вот скриншот ошибки:
[image: ошибка]

**Раньше линукс** на VirtualBox **работал** как дополнительная ОС, внутри Windows10.

На виртуальной машине вот какое сообщение в настройках сети:

[image: не выбран адаптер для подключения к сетевому мосту]

В ходе экспериментов https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ5Kt8ONyBQ&list=PLa1UD0TR2hfYyKFHaRJHCI_RpP97d6EmC
теперь проблема с адаптером не показывается, а показывается такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну это легко гуглится, выбери в типе поключения сеть NAT

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ5Kt8ONyBQ - мне кажется, здесь в правильном направлении, но все-равно не получилось.

Comment: Cложно сказать в правильном направлении ты копаешь или нет, посмотри здесь решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725779/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-vagrant-on-windows10

Comment: Попробую через NAT тоже сейчас, но не уверена, что поможет. Поискала в интернете, помочь должная переустановка виртуальной машины. Но при этом нужно сохранить прежнюю ОС со всеми файлами.

Comment: Если NAT сеть автоматически не определится, тогда вот видео с решением проблемы https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0PMFg-oAEs

Comment: Перейди в инструменты и посмотри подключен ли VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter

Comment: Да, VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter, теперь подключен в VirtualBox (после экспериментов, см. видео, ссылка выше). Но возникает ошибка 80004005 при запуске ОС "Не удалось открыть сессию". То есть это уже другая ошибка, про адаптер уже не оповещается.

Comment: https://lumpics.ru/error-0x80004005-in-virtualbox/ После обновления (repair) virtualBox, линукс стал загружаться, ошибки исчезли. Никаких резервных копий или экспортов не делала.  Настроила сеть NAT. Галочку, где Мост - отключила.

Comment: Пробую отключить NAT, но подключить Мост (с выбором моей сетевой карты Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC) - тоже получается.

Comment: Linux на виртуалке запустился? так что в итоге  помогло?

Comment: Мне кажется, что помогло в итоге обновление виртуальной машины до последней версии. При этом резервных копий линукса не делала, а при установке выбрала repair (а не remove).